# How did 'ликвиди́ровать' semantically shift to mean 'abolish' and 'destroy, kill'?

Tags: этимология

I was reading the etymology of the English ['liquidate'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78589/334589), when I read on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidate#Etymology) that

> The sense "to kill, do away with" is a [semantic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_loan) from [Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language) *[ликвиди́ровать](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)* (likvidírovatʹ), ultimately from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[liquidus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidus#Latin)*.

1. This sense wasn't in the Latin etymon, and thus must have commenced in Russian?
2. Thus how did meaning #2 (the original) develop to 1 and 3? What semantic notions underlie them?

I know that live humans can be killed by [dissolving them in acid](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/france/11793116/French-students-tried-to-dissolve-body-of-murder-victim-in-acid.html), but this method of killing appears too uncommon (I hope!), unethical and frightful to beget this semantic shift?

> 1. to [eliminate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eliminate), to [abolish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abolish)
> 2. to [dissolve](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dissolve)
> 3. to [stamp out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stamp_out), to [do](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/do) away with, to [destroy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/destroy), to [kill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kill) (off)
> 4. to [liquidate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liquidate)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92730/discussion-on-question-by-greek-area-51-proposal-how-did--sema).

Comment: In Russian the "getting rid of" sense is the primary. Killing is secondary (just because it is the most sure cheap way to get rid of a human). The famous examples would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likbez or "liquidating grain loan sharks as a class". Today you can hear about liquidating debts or liquidating unwanted dependencies, etc. Then, a retro-movie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquidation_(miniseries) etc Killing is never a primary meaning but just a specialization of the whole concept for the narrow case.

Comment: @Arioch I wonder -the phrase 'grain loan shark' - did you read it in some book or other source in English?

Comment: @alexsms no, i just put a general description. I could say "world-eaters" (or should it be society-eaters? or peace-eaters?) but it would sound like Harry Potter fanfic without giving any idea who and why were liquidated.

Answer (score 6):

*ликвидировать* initially meant "to convert to liquid assets", as of stock, capital etc.

As converting a business to cash would mean selling it, this word came to mean "to get rid of" and then, by extension, acquired the metaphorical meaning "to kill".

Comment: Источник.   ЛИКВИДИРОВАТЬ
новолатинск. liquidare, от лат. liquere, быть чистым. Уплачивать долги и прекращать торговые дела.
Объяснение 25000 иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русский язык, с означением их корней.- Михельсон А.Д., 1865.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: did 'liquid assets' exist back then where the early dialects of Russian were spoken?

Comment: What early dialects? The earliest mention in the corpus is from around 1860's, and it's a certain borrowing from a European language, most probably French. The meaning of "to get rid of" is around 1890's, that of "to kill" is early 1920's.

Comment: @Quassnoi The first quote in my post (from Wiktionary) contends that *ликвидировать* originated from Latin. Do you know in what year approximately? If this borrowing happened after [modern Russian's onset in 1800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language#Standard_Russian), then I am referring to *ликвидировать* before modern Russian.

Comment: It says "ultimately from Latin", which means it has a root of Latin origin but it's not certain how exactly did this word end up in Russian: might be through French or through German. It does not mean that Latin itself had such a word. As I said, the first mention in the corpus is from 1860's, so the borrowing should not have happened long before that.